# Make IPv6 Server accessible for IPv4 Networks

Tags: proxy, ipv6, web-hosting, ipv4

Old Topic, but anyway:
I have a server at home, which is only accessible via IPv6. Would not be a problem, if there would be more networks around with IPv6 enabled, but currently even my University network is IPv4 only.

Can I create some sort of proxy, which forwards all IPv4 requests via IPv6 to my server? Should be used for more than http.

I would rent a small server at a professional host for this purpose, but I'd like to keep the data at my server at home.

Some advises? Tips or Recommendations?
Best Regards Jounathaen

Comment: `Should be used for more than http.` then you do not just want a (web)proxy. But you could rent a VPS and forward ports from there. (I am assuming that the VPS does do IPv6, since it is now multiple decades old).

Comment: ok, sounds like a good idea. Does this bring any disadvantages, e.g. SSL certificate errors?

Comment: I never set up https websites this way. But maybe someone else can answer that. (Note that I marked your question to be moved to [Su] where it is on-topic rather then [sf] where home servers are looked down upon.

Comment: and other protocols do you want?

Comment: for example: http, https, maybe ftp but also programs like a mumble Server or a Minecraft Server, which (I think) use bare TCP/UDP

Comment: It would depend on how you want to set it up. You could straight up redirect all traffic and/or just certain ports. Alternatively, depending on the application, something like a reverse proxy could help you out. It also would depend on the kind of application whenever you're able to "convince" your backend to behave the way you want it to be.

Comment: A reverse proxy is a good solution. I have used haproxy with success for such cases. If you want a more transparent solution then SIIT-DC is the official solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, I've now set up a cheap VPS and let it run:

```
socat TCP4-LISTEN:443,fork,su=nobody TCP6:[1234:1234:1234:::1234]:443
```

works for me!

edit: for UDP I use:

```
socat UDP4-RECVFROM:443,fork,su=nobody UDP6-SENDTO:[1234:1234:1234:::1234]:443
```

Comment: On CentOS7 this would not work unless started under sudo, stating: `socat[29004] E initgroups(nobody, 99): Operation not permitted`. For my needs I just launched it as a _normal_ user, getting rid of the `su=nobody` option. Awesome oneliner anyway !

Comment: @Arnaud Meuret afaik you need sudo to listen to on any port below 1024 on a Unix system. Good addition, though.

Comment: Yes you're right. I forgot to mention that I was trying to bind to port 4242 when I got this error.